# Let $A$ be a subset of $\Bbb{R}$ such that the following $7$ sets are all different

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am suppose to come up with an example of an subset $A$ such that the sets

$ A$

$int(A)$

$cl(A)$

$ cl(int(A))$

$ int(cl(A))$

$int(cl(int(A)))$

$ cl(int(cl(A)))$

are all different. I am not really sure how to come up with example like that so any hint or idea is great.

Comment: If you can find an example of an $A$ that gives a difference for each _pair_ of descriptions, then you can squash each of those 21 examples into finite space by applying arctan to it, and then translate them away from each other and deliver them all as a single subset ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing with closure and interior to get the maximum number of sets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1443348/playing-with-closure-and-interior-to-get-the-maximum-number-of-sets)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A=[0,1]\cup(2,3)\cup([4,5]\cap\mathbb{Q})\cup\{6\}\cup(7,8)\cup(8,9).$ Then note that :

- $int(A)=(0,1)\cup(2,3)\cup(7,8)\cup(8,9),$
- $cl(A)=[0,1]\cup[2,3]\cup[4,5]\cup\{6\}\cup[7,9],$
- $cl(int(A))=[0,1]\cup[2,3]\cup[7,9],$
- $int(cl(A))=(0,1)\cup(2,3)\cup(4,5)\cup(7,9),$
- $int(cl(int(A)))=(0,1)\cup(2,3)\cup(7,9),$
- $cl(int(cl(A)))=[0,1]\cup[2,3]\cup[4,5]\cup[7,9].$

Comment: I edited that !

Comment: I think also just $A = [(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}] \cup (1,2) \cup (2,3) \cup \{4\}$ works

Comment: @Dan Simon : Yes you are right, and it is more elegant. I tried to add different kinds of sets step-by-step, but it seems there are too numerous now ! ^^